# What is the natural position of 'single-handed(ly)' in this sentence?

Tags: sentence-construction, idiomatic-language, sentence-choice, adverb-placement

> 1. There's some guy who's running around the top floors single-handedly
>    trying to take down the terrorists as if he were Bruce Willis in Die
>    Hard.
> 2. There's some guy who's running around the top floors trying to take
>    down the terrorists single-handed as if he were Bruce Willis in Die
>    Hard.

Hi. How do I incorporate 'single-handed(ly)' in this sentence so it sounds natural (if possible)?

Answer (score 1):

Either would be acceptable. It is a very small difference of emphasis, because of which is mentioned first.

1 emphasizes that he is alone.
2 emphasizes that he is trying to take down the terrorists.

But it is a really small difference. Indeed it is so small that, for some people, it might be reversed depending on whether the thing-in-front is considered more important or less important.